# Probability $1 < X < 6$ given cdf $F_X(x)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> The distribution function of the random variable $X$ is given by
>   $$
> F(x) = \begin{cases}
> 0, & x \le 0 \\
> x/8, & 0 < x \le 7 \\
> 1, & x > 7
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Find $\mathbb{P}[1<x<6]$.

**What I have tried so far:**
$$
\mathbb{P}[1<x<6] = F(6) - F(1) = \frac{6}{8} - \frac{1}{8} = 5/8.
$$

Is $5/8$ is the correct answer? Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic is incorrect but idea is right. Indeed, $F(6) = 6/8$ but $F(1) = 1/8$ not $1/7$ as you claimed.

Comment: Fixed arithmetic error

Comment: @user2501165 yes, $5/8$ is correct.